# How do i connect an azure vm network interface into an azure load balancer address pool?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I have some code which makes multiple vms I'm trying dynamically add them to the load balancer address pool but I'm met with the following error which I have no idea what it means, any help will be appreciated as the error appears to be somewhat obscure

> Error: Error: IP Configuration "azure_network_interface_address_pool_association" was not found on Network Interface "client_host_nic-0" (Resource Group "client_rg")
>
> on vm2.tf line 99, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface_backend_address_pool_association":
>     99: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" {

vm2.tf file includes

```
# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "client_nics" {
    count                     = var.node_count
    name                      = "client_host_nic-${count.index}"
    location                  = var.resource_group_location
    resource_group_name       = module.network.azurerm_resource_group_client_name
#    network_security_group_id = module.network.bastion_host_network_security_group

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "client_host_nic"
        subnet_id                     = module.network.client_subnet_id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
#        public_ip_address_id          = module.network.bastion_host_puplic_ip_address #optional field we have a bastion host so no need for public IP also its vnet peered so this adds an extra layer of securit in a way
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId_Generator" {
    keepers = {
        # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
        resource_group = var.resource_group_location
    }

    byte_length = 8
}


# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "client_storageaccount" {
    name                        = "diag${random_id.randomId_Generator.hex}"
    resource_group_name         = module.network.azurerm_resource_group_client_name
    location                    = var.resource_group_location
    account_tier                = "Standard"
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "node" {
  count                 = var.node_count
  name                  = "client-host-${count.index}"
  location              = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name   = module.network.azurerm_resource_group_client_name
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.client_nics.*.id, count.index)}"]

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
   delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
   delete_data_disks_on_termination = true  

  # 1 vCPU, 3.5 Gb of RAM
  vm_size = var.machine_type

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myOsDisk-${count.index}"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
        computer_name  = "Production"
        admin_username = "azureuser"
    }

  os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = true
        ssh_keys {
            path     = "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys" #This cannot be changed as mentioned in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html
            key_data = file("~/.ssh/client.pub")

        }
    }

    boot_diagnostics {
        enabled = "true"
        storage_uri = azurerm_storage_account.client_storageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" {
  count                 = var.node_count
  network_interface_id    = element(azurerm_network_interface.client_nics.*.id, count.index) #fixes interpolation issues
  ip_configuration_name   = "azure_network_interface_address_pool_association"
  backend_address_pool_id = module.loadbalancer.azure_backend_pool_id
}
```

load balancer module main.tf file

```
#rember when using this module to call the network module for the resource group name
############## load balancer section  ##############
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "azure_load_balancer_IP" {
  name                = "azure_load_balancer_IP"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "azure_load_balancer" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "front_end_IP_configuration_for_azure_load_balancer"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.azure_load_balancer_IP.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_address_pool" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.azure_load_balancer.id
  name                = "BackEndAddressPool"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "azure_lb_rule" {
  resource_group_name            = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.azure_load_balancer.id
  name                           = "LBRule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "front_end_IP_configuration_for_azure_load_balancer"
}
```

output.tf

```
output "azure_load_balancer_ip" {
  value = azurerm_public_ip.azure_load_balancer_IP.id
}

output "azure_backend_pool_id" {
  value = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_address_pool.id
}
```

additional information

```
* provider.azurerm: version = "~> 2.1"
```

main.tf

```
module "loadbalancer" {
 source = "./azure_load_balancer_module" #this may need to be a different git repo as we are not referencing branches here only the master
resource_group_name = module.network.azurerm_resource_group_client_name
  resource_group_location = var.resource_group_location
 }
```

Comment: Did some digging it appears that this is a known bug with terraform https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3794

Comment: How do you quote the load balancer module in the VM file? I can see nothing about the module.

Comment: wait How you mean, so I had assumed it was referenced through the azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association?, ideally it would be module.loadbalancer.(a resource that needs to be called form the output) so i guess maybe theres something missing in the load balancer module which should be referecned?

Comment: Do you solve the problem with the solution? Or any more questions?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test at the moment, I will test a little bit later on in the week and get back to you

Comment: @CharlesXu just run the code got

Comment: Error: Code="VmIsNotInSameAvailabilitySetAsLb"

Comment: Does the LB is in the same region and subscription of the tenant as the VM? Additionally, please @ me if you send the message to me, it will let me get it as possible as quick.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu so the VM's are in the same tennant and subscription, I don't know if they need to be an availability set to add it to the LB I suspect they might need to be the location is "UK south" for all resources. So really just looking to see what the error is about and trying to understand if it possible to attach VM's to the Azure load balancer preferably not as an availability set

Comment: Yeah, the VM should be in the same region with the Load Balancer, and also, the public IP of the VM should be the same SKU with the Load Balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the **Ipconfiguration name** you set for the network interface is not the same as you set for the resource `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association`. You can take a look at the description for `ip_configuration_name` [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.html#argument-reference). And as I see, you want to associate multiple interfaces with the load balancer.

So I recommend you change the network interface and the association like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "client_nics" {
    count                     = var.node_count
    name                      = "client_host_nic-${count.index}"
    location                  = var.resource_group_location
    resource_group_name       = module.network.azurerm_resource_group_client_name
#    network_security_group_id = module.network.bastion_host_network_security_group

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "client_host_nic-${count.index}"
        subnet_id                     = module.network.client_subnet_id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
#       public_ip_address_id          = module.network.bastion_host_puplic_ip_address #optional field we have a bastion host so no need for public IP also its vnet peered so this adds an extra layer of securit in a way
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" {
  count                 = var.node_count
  network_interface_id    = element(azurerm_network_interface.client_nics.*.id, count.index) #fixes interpolation issues
  ip_configuration_name   = "client_host_nic-${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = module.loadbalancer.azure_backend_pool_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a bug with the azure 2.1 terraform provider and seems to have been fixed in version 2.33 according to upstream https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3794